# firstChild of an element in JavaScript constructor class

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6, bind

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't properly access firstChild of an element object in a JavaScript class. I can set innerHTML without the firstChild properly, but I'd like to set it on firstChild. Using console.dir(this.waitStatus) shows that it has a firstChild. I'm not using jQuery because it may not be loaded when I want this run, since it is a loading indicator.

```
    class LoadingIndicator{

        constructor(elementID){

            this.tick = 8;

            this.waitStatus = document.getElementById(elementID);

            setInterval(
                this.animateLoader.bind(this),
                10
            )        

        }

        animateLoader (){        

            if(this.tick == 8){

                this.waitStatus.firstChild.innerHTML = ".";

            }
            else if(this.tick == 16){

                this.waitStatus.firstChild.innerHTML = "..";

            }else if(this.tick == 24){

                this.waitStatus.firstChild.innerHTML = "...";

                this.tick = 0;

            }

            this.tick += 1;

        }

    }

var supervisorLoadingIndicator = new LoadingIndicator('supervisorsTableLoading');
```

**html**

```
<p id='supervisorsTableLoading' style='width:700px; height:0px; text-align:left; padding-bottom:20px;'>
<span id='supervisorsTableLoadingInner' style='margin-left:30%'>&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

Comment: The `firstChild` is a text node *(the line break before the `<span`)*, so `.innerHTML` isn't useful. Use `.firstElementChild` instead, or `.children[0]`.

Comment: That was it thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. See the notes I added below about browser compatibility too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `firstChild` is a text node *(the line break before the `<span`)*, so `.innerHTML` isn't useful. Use `.firstElementChild` instead, or `.children[0]`.

```
class LoadingIndicator {
    constructor(elementID) {
        this.tick = 8;
        this.waitStatus = document.getElementById(elementID);
        setInterval(this.animateLoader.bind(this), 10)        
    }

    animateLoader () {        
        if (this.tick == 8) {
            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = ".";

        } else if (this.tick == 16) {
            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "..";

        } else if (this.tick == 24) {
            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "...";
            this.tick = 0;
        }
        this.tick += 1;
    }
}

var supervisorLoadingIndicator = new LoadingIndicator('supervisorsTableLoading');
```

Or you could simply get rid of that whitespace text and use `.firstChild`.

---

Also, you're not really setting HTML content, so I'd personally use `.textContent` instead.

```
this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.textContent = "...";
```

IE8 and lower don't support either of these properties.

If you're still supporting IE8, then you can polyfill them both.

If you're supporting IE6/7, then stick with `.innerHTML` and get rid of that whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

use this.waitStatus.children[0], firstChild will return non element node.

```js
class LoadingIndicator{

        constructor(elementID){
            
            this.tick = 8;

            this.waitStatus = document.getElementById(elementID);
            console.log(this.waitStatus.firstChild);
            setInterval(
                this.animateLoader.bind(this),
                10
            )        

        }

        animateLoader (){        
            if(this.tick == 8){

                this.waitStatus.children[0].innerHTML = ".";

            }
            else if(this.tick == 16){

                this.waitStatus.children[0].innerHTML = "..";

            }else if(this.tick == 24){

                this.waitStatus.children[0].innerHTML = "...";

                this.tick = 0;

            }

            this.tick += 1;

        }

    }

var supervisorLoadingIndicator = new LoadingIndicator('supervisorsTableLoading');
```

```html
<p id='supervisorsTableLoading' style='width:700px; height:0px; text-align:left; padding-bottom:20px;'>
<span id='supervisorsTableLoadingInner' style='margin-left:30%'>&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```